# PySide6 pixelates PNGs

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside6

When im trying to add a PNG to PySide6 GUI it loses in quality.
Here is the code:

```py
import sys
import random
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PySide6.QtGui import QPalette, QColor

BOARD_SIZE = 4


class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.resize(500, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("2048")

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

        # QtWidgets.QApplication.setGraphicsSystem('native')

        for i in range(BOARD_SIZE):
            for j in range(BOARD_SIZE):
                path = "./img/" + randomTile() + ".png"
                img = QtGui.QImage(path)
                pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(img.scaledToWidth(150))
                label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
                label.setPixmap(pixmap)
                grid.addWidget(label, i, j)

        self.setLayout(grid)


def randomTile():
    tiles = ['tile0', 'tile2', 'tile4', 'tile8', 'tile16', 'tile32', 'tile64', 'tile128', 'tile256', 'tile512',
             'tile1024', 'tile2048', 'tile4096', 'tile8192', 'tile16384', 'tile32768', 'tile65536', 'tile131072']
    return tiles[random.randint(0, len(tiles) - 1)]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Original image:

[image: Original image]

After the quality loss:

[image: After the quality loss]

The .scaledToWidth() function isn't the problem, as the image without it in the program is still pixelated:

[image: no .scaledToWidth()]

I would like to emphasize that the problem doesn't lay in scaling. Quality is messed up even without scaling.

Comment: [`scaledToWidth`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#scaledToWidth) ***is*** the problem. Change to: `img.scaledToWidth(150, QtCore.Qt.TransformationMode.SmoothTransformation)`

Comment: [Result after adding Your function](https://imgur.com/a/Vs7DV3F)

Comment: I just tried your code with the original image you posted in the question and it does **not** create that output. Please specify your Qt version and OS and if that screenshot is actually taken from the code above.

Comment: Edition Windows 10 Home
Version 20H2
Installed on ‎23.‎03.‎2021
OS build 19042.1466
Experience Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3920.0

PySide6 version: 6.2.2.1

Thats really wierd, thank you for your time - and yes all the screenshots are legit.

Comment: Also, is the "original image" the *actual* original image you're using? Because if it's not, you should post *that*, possibly specifying the current image data (image format, image and file size, color format, alpha data, etc), then embed it in the code and also, to be 100% sure, test again the code above with the *uploaded* image (as imgur applies compression).

Comment: [Losseless PNG that im using](https://u.cubeupload.com/MDDawid1/tile64.png) I have tried this code many times with all transformation/scaling methods I could find (I tried it without any scaling at all and it is pixelated too).

Comment: Are you saying that if you directly use `pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(img)` you get a pixelated image? Also, there's something that is unclear to me: in your code you're resizing to 150x150, but the two images shown have very different sizes. How are you getting those images? Do you have DPI scaling enabled on your system? Is there a specific reason for which you're passing through QImage instead of directly loading the QPixmap (aka: have you tried to just load the QPixmap with the file path)?

Comment: There is no reson why i used QImage, I have now changed it to Your way but the result is the same. Only 2nd image in my post is scaled. 1st is the original one and 3rd is image after just passing it to PySide without any scaling.

Comment: What about DPI scaling/HiDPI (`print(app.devicePixelRatio(), app.primaryScreen().devicePixelRatio())`)? Can you try with PySide2 (it's important to understand if it's a problem that was introduced in Qt6)? I'd suggest you to create a *very basic* example (no tiles, just a basic label set as central widget, using one of the files), since it seems clear that the problem is just about that. (OT: use `random.choice` to select items in a list, and make the list a global variable or instance attribute (so you don't rebuild it every time), otherwise: `return 'tile' + str(2**randrange(18) // 2 * 2)`)

Comment: ```app.devicePixelRatio(), app.primaryScreen().devicePixelRatio()``` returns **1.25 1.25**. I just tried creating basic label using PySide2 and there is no pixelation, so it is caused by Qt6. (also thank you for random.choice tip)

Comment: I don't own a HiDPI screen, so (luckily? ;-) ) I've never had the opportunity to dig more into that. The problem comes from dealing with non-integer scaling (which introduces aliasing); I don't really know how this exactly works with QPixmap painting, but you should check if [`devicePixelRatio()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#devicePixelRatio) matches the screen (and eventually try override it with that value), and also carefully read [High DPI Support in Qt](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html#high-dpi-support-in-qt), especially `QGuiApplication.setHighDpiScaleFactorRoundingPolicy()`.